# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Search returning Keys

Tags: php, arrays, search, key, associative-array

I am trying to search an array of arrays and if the needle is found I want to return or at least know the keys for the match.

For example given:

```
['foo'] => 
     ['bar'] => 'blah'
```

Searching for '*blah*' I need to know there is a match and the keys are '*foo*' and '*bar*'

I have managed to implement a search which returns boolean for a match:

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
        if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach($haystack as $element) {
            var_dump($element);
            if(is_array($element) && $this->search_array($needle, $element))
               return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

But I am struggling with how to know the keys. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. One solution is to:

- In the base case utilize [array_search()](http://php.net/array_search) to get the key.
- In the recursive case, when iterating over each element in the haystack (before recursing) use  the `$key => $value` syntax of [foreach](http://php.net/foreach). Then when the recursive call yields a value, check if the returned value is an array (by using [is_array()](http://php.net/is_array)) - if so, use [array_unshift()](http://php.net/array_unshift) to push the current key onto the returned array. Otherwise return an array with the key and the returned value.

  ```
  function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
      if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return array_search($needle, $haystack);
      }
      foreach($haystack as $key => $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element)) {
              $searchReturn = search_array($needle, $element);
              if (is_array($searchReturn)) {
                  array_unshift($searchReturn, $key);
                  return $searchReturn;
              }
              return [$key, $searchReturn];
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/rbsmMw35uvfPoYYs).

Comment: Thanks that worked albeit I had to modify the return at line 3 to in_array in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, since it's 2-dimensional array.

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $needle) {
            return array($key);
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                if ($v == $needle) {
                    return array($key, $k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For an n-dimensional array you should use a recursive function...

Comment: This is an interesting non-recursive solution, thnaks